# MYSQL LIKE REGEXP

Tags: php, sql, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь сделать проверку на совпадения в БД.
Привожу к единому виду переменную для проверки -

```
$title_check = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9]/iu','',$title_check);
$title_check = 'ОООВЕКАСТРОЙ';
```

На выходе имя в верхнем регистре, только буквы и цифры.
Не могу понять какой запрос сделать к БД, чтобы он приводил сначала проверяемое поле к такому же виду и затем проверял. Поиски в гугле привели к функции REGEXP.
Пытался написать что-то вроде

```
SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE node.type='zastr' AND title LIKE REGEXP ('/[^\p{L}0-9]/iu', $title_check)
```

но это конечно же неправильно.

Как написать такой запрос? Сразу оговорюсь - SOUNDS LIKE не подойдёт, MATCH AGAINST не подойдёт - таблица InnoDB.

Comment: В MySQL нет изменяющих RegExp - только проверка на соответствие шаблону. Так что либо выполняйте "приведение к единому виду" на уровне приложения, либо подключайте к серверу сторонние UDF, выполняющие операцию изменения по регулярному выражению.

Comment: Начиная с 5.6 полнотекстовый поддерживается для иннодб

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в Mysql нет оператора `LIKE REGEXP`, а есть два разных оператора LIKE и REGEXP.
Поэтому надо выбрать только один.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM person
WHERE memo REGEXP '[[:<:]]John[[:>:]]'
AND memo REGEXP '[[:<:]]Smith[[:>:]]
```